# Display a Matlab struct as a table

Tags: matlab

I have a struct. I want to display the content of this struct as a table. So I use the following transformation:

```
 aTable = struct2table(aStruct); 
 disp(aTable);
```

which returns

```
aStruct =

   LocalName: {'example.cdf'}
        Size: '1 KB'
ModifiedTime: '10-May-2010 21:35:00'

aTable = 

  LocalName      Size    ModifiedTime
_____________    ____    ____________
'example.cdf'    1 KB    [1x20 char]
```

The value of `modifiedTime` is not correct. I hope to display it as a value, not as an array. Can you tell me how I can do that?

Comment: That's perfectly right. A string is a character array. Edit: otherwise you have to use a cell as you did for `LocalName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string is longer than 10 chars, it will display its size rather than the string itself. Cellstrings displays the string up to 143 chars and then truncates with `...`. This effect is inherited from an internal call to `evalc(cellstr)`.

```
struct2table(struct('Char10', '1234567890', 'Char11','11234567890','Cellstring11',{{repmat('1',1,144)}}))
ans = 
      Char10        Char11                                                                         Cellstring11                                                                  
    __________    ___________    ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
    1234567890    [1x11 char]    '111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111…'
```

To solve your issue, once converted to table:

```
aTable.ModifiedTime = cellstr(aTable.ModifiedTime);
```